# Scraping JS contents of a site using perl

Tags: javascript, perl, jsp, mechanize

I'm scrapping this [site](http://global.krx.co.kr/contents/GLB/02/0203/0203000000/GLB0203000000.jsp) and am looking for code examples to help me figure out how to retrieve the information inside of this JSP control (it's a lot harder than with regular text!). I don't seem to be finding anything with the HTTP headers. Here's my code so far:

```
 my $mech_r = new WWW::Mechanize();

 my $uri = 'http://global.krx.co.kr/contents/GLB/02/0203/0203000000/GLB0203000000.jsp';
 print "Getting '$uri'\n";
 my $page = $mech_r->get($uri);

 print "Parsing data...";
 my $root = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($mech_r->content());

 my ($news_table) = $root->look_down(
     sub {
         defined($_[0]->tag()) and
         $_[0]->tag() eq 'ul' and
         defined($_[0]->attr('class')) and
         $_[0]->attr('class') eq 'board-list'
     }
 );

 if (!defined($news_table)) {
     print Dumper($root);

     croak "Could not get the news table";
 }
```

I would like to get the title, date and the link.

But is not getting any data as it is being loaded by javascript.

Answer (score 3):

As documented, [WWW::Mechanize](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize) doesn't handle JavaScript. Try [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox), [WWW::Scripter](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Scripter), [WWW::Selenium](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Selenium), [WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS), or similar.

Comment: im trying Selenium but I got stuck on running the server


>> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar                      
03:05:27.879 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@2a5330

Comment: Just for future viewers, don't try  WWW::Mechanize::Firefox and WWW::Selenium, both projects are eol